# Which tag(s) to use for Python typing questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Python added type annotations, and since they're very new, there are a large number of questions about how to use them. People use different tags to mark these questions:

1. [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [type-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-hinting) (140 questions)
2. [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [typechecking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typechecking) (63 questions)
3. [mypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mypy) (55 questions)
4. [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typing) (49 questions)
5. [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) and [static-typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static-typing) (25 questions)

and occasionally something like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/types) (891 questions, almost none of which are about type annotations).

[mypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mypy) is the most actively used type checker, and all [mypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mypy) questions are actually just general type annotation questions, not specific to [mypy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mypy) (at least I haven't seen any question specific to mypy extensions).

Should we manually change all these tags to the most popular one ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [type-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-hinting)) when we see them to make the tagging more consistent?

Too bad synonyms cannot be defined to map a pair of tags into a single tag or vice versa; otherwise we could map everything to the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) [type-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-hinting) pair.

UPDATE:

I'll wait until Tuesday 4/11 to get any additional comments.

The concerns expressed by @BhargavRao is that automatic retagging will bump the new tag to the home page causing [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) to be flooded with type-related questions. Currently, there are ~2.5 [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) questions updated per minute. I'd retag questions at 1/10th of that rate, or 1 question every 4 minutes. This means retagging will complete within ~1 day (~300 questions total). Of course, I can lower the rate if someone thinks it's too fast.

The script logic I have in mind is:

- Find all questions that are tagged with any of the tag combinations #2 through #5 (listed above) and that don't have [type-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-hinting).
- Every 4 minutes, select one question, and if there's enough tag slots left, add [type-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-hinting).

I think removing tags is too dangerous, although I'm open to suggestions.

I'll share the script in case anyone wants to run it in the future again.

I hope that Stack Overflow automated tag suggestion system will notice that [type-hinting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/type-hinting) is used for questions with certain keywords, and will often suggest it for new typing-related questions.

If anyone has any ideas about how to use synonym system to help reduce inconsistent tagging of this topic, maybe add a comment?

EDIT: The retagging started. I removed a few irrelevant questions manually from the queue, and set the earliest allowed date to 2015-01-01 because PEP 484 was all but unknown until then. I also increased the delay to 10 min.

UPDATE: A moderator alerted me to the problem with my script unintentionally converting markdown to the much noisier HTML. I stopped the retagging and rolled back the changes. I do not want to risk automatic retagging again, even after I fix the problem. But if any moderator wants a list of questions that should be retagged, I have it.

Comment: Unless someone thinks it's a bad idea, I'll update all tags to add type-hinting if any of the other combinations is present.

Comment: I'd prefer [tag:type-hinting] as the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing) clearly mention that the module is a support for "type hints". And yes, mass retaging *is* a bad idea. You'll be bumping the tag to the home page and in the process, annoying multiple users who are following [tag:python].

Comment: I don't have an opinion about it but I would give it another 24 hours before you start. It is sunday in large parts of the world ....

Comment: @BhargavRao is it ok to do it in small batches?

Comment: It's only been a few hours since you posted this proposal.  It would be better to wait until you get some feedback from the community before embarking on a retagging project.

Comment: Community managers have a tool to do batch retagging which does not bump the posts in the process.

Comment: @TinyGiant So, should we ask community managers to do this instead of doing it from a user-level script?

Comment: If this initiative were to gain widespread support, that would be the least intrusive course of action.